# Add Product categories to Wordpress menu without losing hierarchy

Tags: categories, menus, woocommerce-offtopic, sub-menu, hierarchical

I need to add product categories to Wordpress menu, but when I'm doing this with WP interface it lose the hierarchy
[image: wordpress menu losing hierarchy]

I tried with WP-CLI, but there is no method to specify wich item is the child.

There is a method to do it? There is a ton of categories (3-4 level deep), I cannot do this manually

I can buy also a plugin. Can you suggest something?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Instead of a nav menu, you could use `woocommerce_product_categories()`. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/94168/woocommerce-list-all-categories